# What is an Image™?

Tags: visual

Inspired by JLee's original Word™/Phrase™ series.

---

If an Image™ meets certain requirements, I call it an Image™ else I call it a fake Image™. Here are some examples of Images™ and fake Images™.

Images™

Image™ 1:
[image]

Image™ 2:
[image]

Image™ 3:
[image]

Fake Images™

Fake Image™ 1:
[image]

Fake Image™ 2:
[image]

Fake Image™ 3:
[image]

Fake Image™ 4:
[image]

Fake Image™ 5:
[image]

Fake Image™ 6:
[image]

What is an Image™?

Comment: Would the puzzle be ruined if we used the scaled down versions of the images imgur automatically generates?

Comment: @Bass It won't be ruined. The images are this large on accident actually.

Comment: To show an example of how it's done, I edited the post to use the ["t size"](https://api.imgur.com/models/image#thumbs) images with links to the originals, feel free to re-edit as you see fit.

Comment: This is an easy puzzle, surprised that nobody has answered it yet.

Comment: There are many possible differences that I see. For example, having two colors/having more than two colors, being divided into at most five regions/being divided into more than five regions, all regions touch a border/some regions don't touch a border, has no acute angles/has acute angles... There's no clear reason to choose one answer over another.

Comment: I changed my upvote to a downvote because it's become clear that six images are in no way enough to determine the final answer. Without further info, there are a whole multitude of answers that are hugely plausible.

Comment: @new Q Open Wild okay.

Comment: @newQOpenWid I have edited it to have three more Fakes.

Comment: 2 downvotes... Strange, I expected the number would go down since I edited the question.

Comment: Actually it's 4 downvotes - they're just masked by 2 upvotes.

Comment: @newQOpenWid Well the 2 upvotes negated 2 downvotes so now there are 2 downvotes. Not 4 downvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking a wild stab here. An Image™ is one that

> uses exactly two colors and that all edges are straight (as mentioned by new Q Open Wid)

Comment: You are half correct, there is another requirement though.

Comment: @The_AH, perhaps you could provide me with some counter-examples, since my solution works for the six examples you provided.

Comment: I am going to update the puzzle to make it a bit more harder since it's too simple right now.

Comment: @The_AH This means I might change some of the requirements or introduce new requirements.

Comment: With the new fake images, there is probably an additional requirement that all edges are straight.

Comment: @newQOpenWid, I wonder whether theres a better phrase than all edges are straight, since technically every pixel is kinda discrete and no curves exist in a digital image.

Comment: Correct answer.